# Plot points overlapping when rotating points on xy-plane

Tags: python

The point of the spot marked (comment says "marked spot") is to rotate the existing points in a 3D plot by one spot.  Basically I'm moving all points 60 degrees.  For some reason when moving the points I am having two points overlap.  I have tried changing my if statement, and have messed around with he indices, but have not been successful. The only reason I included the entire function is so you can plot and see the problem I am having.  Here it is; let me know if you have any questions:

```
def transform_3d_trig(a,b,c):
        q=2*math.pi/(360)
        d=c*q
        a2 = a+b
        n = 12

        sin=math.sin
        cos=math.cos
        sqrt=math.sqrt
        x = []
        y = []
        z = []

        for i in range(n):
            if i <= 5:
                x.append(a*np.cos(q*(60*(i-1))))
                y.append(a*np.sin(q*(60*(i-1))))
                z.append(0)
            else:
                x.append(a2*np.cos(q*(60*(i-1))))
                y.append(a2*np.sin(q*(60*(i-1))))
                z.append(0)

        x_new = x #new lists
        y_new = y
        z_new = z
        for i in range(n):
            y_new[i] = y[i]*cos(d)
            z_new[i] = y_new[i]*np.tan(d)

        # plot points at this stage (before rotation); no overlapping points
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
        ax3 = fig.add_subplot(211, projection='3d')
        bond2 = [x_new[4],x_new[10],y_new[4],y_new[10],z_new[4],z_new[10]]
        ax3.plot(bond2[:2],bond2[2:4],bond2[4:6], color='r')
        ax3.scatter(x_new, y_new, z_new)
        ax3.set_xlabel('\nX')
        ax3.set_ylabel('\nY')
        ax3.set_zlabel('\nZ')

        x_dummy = x_new #dummy variables to not screw up list
        y_dummy = y_new
        for i in range(n): #marked spot
            if (i == 5 or i == 11):
                x_new[i] = x_dummy[i-5]
                y_new[i] = y_dummy[i-5]
            else:
                x_new[i] = x_dummy[i+1]
                y_new[i] = y_dummy[i+1]

            print(x_new[i], y_new[i]) #to track what point are overlapping

        # plot points at this stage (after rotation); overlapping points
        ax3 = fig.add_subplot(212, projection='3d')
        bond2 = [x_new[4],x_new[10],y_new[4],y_new[10],z_new[4],z_new[10]]
        ax3.plot(bond2[:2],bond2[2:4],bond2[4:6], color='r')
        ax3.scatter(x_new, y_new, z_new)
        ax3.set_xlabel('\nX')
        ax3.set_ylabel('\nY')
        ax3.set_zlabel('\nZ')
        plt.show()
        return x, y, z, x_new, y_new, z_new
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that these lines don't do what you expect:

```
x_dummy = x_new
y_dummy = y_new
```

They don't create copies of your arrays but just duplicate the references. As a result you are actually 'screwing up' your original `_new` arrays when modifying the `_dummy` 'versions' because they are (references to) the same object.

To achieve the behaviour you are looking for (I assume), you would need to force the actual copy of the data:

```
x_dummy = x_new.copy()
y_dummy = y_new.copy()
```

Comment: Sorry, my comment made in confusing.  The x_new, y_new, and z_new are lists, not arrays.  My bad again.  i will edit my original post.

Comment: Just the same. You duplicate the references, not copy the content.

Comment: it gives me an error " 'list' object has no attribute 'copy' "

Comment: for copying lists you can use `x_dummy = x_new[:]`

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked.  Was ready to pull my hair out :)